# Boost serialization base class without default constructor

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

**How to serialize/deserialize derived class inheriting base class without default constructor?**
Please offer serializing boost functions for the following classes

```
struct Base
{
  Base(int b) : b(b) {}
  const int b;
}

struct Derived : public Base
{
  Derived(float d, int b) : Base(b), d(d) {}
  const float d;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use-case straddles two of the "special considerations" documented by Boost Serialization:

- [Non-default constructors](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors)
- [Pointers to objects of derived classes](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#derivedpointers)

Note that I'm going to assume you want dynamic polymorphism, and to get this you need at least a virtual destructor. If you don't you will end up with Undefined Behaviour.

---

Combining the two for your example:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15a31f5b5633066c)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    Base(int b) : b(b) {}
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    const int b;
};

namespace boost::serialization {
    template <typename Ar> inline void serialize(Ar&, Base&, unsigned) {}

    template <typename Ar>
    inline void save_construct_data(Ar& ar, Base const* p, unsigned) {
        // save data required to construct instance
        ar << p->b;
    }

    template <typename Ar>
    inline void load_construct_data(Ar& ar, Base* p, unsigned) {
        int attribute;
        ar >> attribute;
        // invoke inplace constructor to initialize instance
        ::new (p) Base(attribute);
    }
} // namespace boost::serialization

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived(float d, int b) : Base(b), d(d) {}
    const float d;
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Base)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived)

namespace boost::serialization {
    template <typename Ar> inline void serialize(Ar& ar, Derived& d, unsigned) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(d);
    }
    template <typename Ar>
    inline void save_construct_data(Ar& ar, Derived const* p, unsigned) {
        // save data required to construct instance
        ar & p->b & p->d;
    }

    template <typename Ar>
    inline void load_construct_data(Ar& ar, Derived* p, unsigned) {
        int b;
        float d;

        ar & b & d;
        // invoke inplace constructor to initialize instance
        ::new (p) Derived(d, b);
    }
} // namespace boost::serialization

std::string save(Base* b) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);
        oa << b;
    }
    return oss.str();
}

Base* load(std::string txt) {
    std::istringstream iss(std::move(txt));
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);
    Base* b = nullptr;
    ia >> b;
    return b;
}

int main() {
    for (Base* object :
         {
             new Base(-99),
             static_cast<Base*>(new Derived(3.14, 42)),
         }) //
    {
        std::cout << "----\n";
        Base* roundtrip = load(save(object));

        delete object;
        std::cout << "roundtrip: b=" << roundtrip->b;
        if (auto* as_derived = dynamic_cast<Derived const*>(roundtrip)) {
            std::cout << ", d=" << as_derived->d;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        delete roundtrip;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
----
roundtrip: b=-99
----
roundtrip: b=42, d=3.14
```

### SAFETY FIRST

Of course, don't use raw new/delete:

1. using `unique_ptr` **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d96c0f9d93cb5ec)**
2. using `shared_ptr` (note the [`dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast))  **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/134f3e6350dd03ad)**

Comment: yep, that's the landmark solution for this case, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The lack of a default constructor is the least of the problems here.

This class cannot be deserialized, as is. Once an instance of this class is constructed its `const` class members will veto any further attempts to deserialize anything.

In this particular case your only option is to deserialize a lonely `int` and a `float` by themself. Then use the deserialized `int` and `float` to construct the class.

Comment: This is not accurate. Yes the class design is problematic, but Boost Serialization has a loop-hole for just about everything under the sun.

Comment: I can see why C++ carries such a stellar reputation, when something like that gets presented as a clean solution. What a showcase of placement new, multiple layers of overloading, and other examples of perfect clarity. C++ newcomers, that want to implement simple, basic, serialization of an object with a `const` class member, won't have any trouble immediately understanding every one of those moving pieces.

Comment: I don't see *anyone* call this a clean solution, and also, the problem is with the class design as you and I have reiterated.